# Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll not including shapes

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I work in a software development environment with the same file and reference path for Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll (we included it in our projects in an Assemblies folder). Two of my co-workers are able to successfully open the designer of a form that uses the PowerPacks, but I cannot. I'm getting the error

> Could not find type Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.ShapeContainer.

When I look at my Toolbox, I see the Visual Basic PowerPacks, but it only has the Pointer and PrintForm. In my googling and goggling today, I discovered that this version of PowerPacks is in Visual Studio 2008 SP1, so I went to check my version type, only to discover that it's the .4462 QFE for my SQL Server R2 install.

But when I scroll down the list of Installed Products, I don't see the 'Microsoft Visual Studio Team System 2008 Team Suite - ENU Service Pack 1 (KB945140) KB945140' line anywhere.

I know that SQL Server R2 required the Visual Studio 2008 SP1 to be installed if Visual Studio 2008 was installed first, but what happens when Visual Studio is installed ***after*** SQL Server? Could my problem be that I'm not up to SP1? Is there a way to tell?